# Create Table and Insert Data into a SQLite Database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to Check if a table exists in a database in my app. If the table doesnt exist I need to create and Insert one record into it. The only problem here is that each time it will insert a new record, and I only need one record in that database. What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I just check if the database exists then only run this code if it doesnt, or is there another way I should be going about this?

```
NSString *strSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"Version\" (\"Type\" TEXT,\"Number\" DOUBLE DEFAULT (null) )";
const char *chrStmt = [strSQL UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *cmpStmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_stats, chrStmt, -1, &cmpStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    sqlite3_step(cmpStmt);
}
sqlite3_finalize(cmpStmt);

strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Version (Type, Number) VALUES ('Database', %f);", db_version];
const char *chrStmt2 = [strSQL UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db_stats, chrStmt2, -1, &cmpStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    sqlite3_step(cmpStmt);
}
sqlite3_finalize(cmpStmt);
```

Comment: I think, your problem can be solved by using NSUserDefaults as you are going to insert only one record .